# String.split() --- How do I treat consecutive delimiters as one?

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

For two sample strings in variable temp such as these:

```
(1) "|RYVG|111|9|"
(2) "|RYVG|111||9|"
```

I want to do the following:

```
String splitRating[] = temp.split("\\|",);
```

But I want the result to be the same, which is:

```
splitrating[0] = ""
splitrating[1] = "RYVG"
splitrating[2] = "111"
splitrating[3] = "9
```

This means that I need to treat that double "|" as one delimiter. Is there any way to do this while still using `String.split()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add a `+` to match one or more instances of the pipe:

```
temp.split("\\|+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
String splitRating[] = temp.split("\\|+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

```
 class  Split
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String temp="|RYVG|111||9|";

    String splitRating[] = temp.split("\\|+");

    for(String split:splitRating){
    System.out.println(split);
}
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringUtils` split method considers the consecutive delimiters as one delimiter.

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split("|");
```